# Issue with replacing Java DTO classes with Kotlin Data classes

Tags: java, kotlin, dto

I read about Kotlin data classes and thought that they could be pretty useful in cases with describing data transfer objects (DTOs). In my Java project I already has DTO classes written on Java, something like:

```
public class Tweet {
    private String id;
    private String profileId;
    private String message;

    public Tweet() {}

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getProfileId() {
        return profileId;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setProfileId(String profileId) {
        this.profileId = profileId;
    }

    public Tweet setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
        return this;
    }
}
```

These DTO classes are stored in separate artifact which I add as a dependency to other artifacts. So, I decided to replace it with Kotlin classes and rewrote mentioned Tweet class on Kotlin, so it started to looks like:

```
data class Tweet(var id: String? = null,
                 var profileId: String? = null,
                 var message: String? = null)
```

It's my first experience with Kotlin, so possibly there are something that can looks ugly, but my main issue is - when I try to rebuild artifacts which use my DTOs as dependencies, I get such exception:

> at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2992)
>   at io.vertx.core.json.Json.decodeValue(Json.java:117)
>   at gk.tweetsched.api.repository.TweetRepository.get(TweetRepository.java:51)
>   at gk.tweetsched.api.repository.TweetRepositoryTest.testGet(TweetRepositoryTest.java:68)
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   kotlin.jvm.internal.DefaultConstructorMarker
>   at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
>   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
>   at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
>   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
>   ... 67 more

As I see according that stacktrace Jackson couldn't deserialize JSON to Tweet Kotlin class.

Here is my Java method where I get that exception:

```
public Tweet get(String id) {
    try (Jedis jedis = pool.getResource()) {
        return Json.decodeValue(jedis.hget(TWEETS_HASH, id), Tweet.class);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error(e);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Where Json class is from 'io.vertx.core.json' package.

How can I fix that issue? Which additional configurations should I make in my Java projects to use Kotlin classes?

Comment: Do you use the `jackson-module-kotlin` extension? See https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-kotlin

Comment: Seems we had the same idea :)

Comment: I use io.vertx.core.json.Json class, which use Jackson as I see in debug. I'll update a bit the question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

By default Jackson needs a parameterless constructor to deserialize JSON to a class - Kotlin data classes do not have one, so you need to add a Jackson module to handle this:

[jackson-module-kotlin](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-kotlin)

Edit:
I've read the [source for io.vertx.core.json.Json class](https://github.com/eclipse/vert.x/blob/master/src/main/java/io/vertx/core/json/Json.java) and it seems that both object mappers used by the class are stored in public static fields.

So to register [jackson-module-kotlin](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-kotlin) you need to include this snippet in your application initialization code (or anywhere else really as long as it is executed before you attempt to deserialize any Kotlin data classes):

```
Json.mapper.registerModule(new KotlinModule())
Json.prettyMapper.registerModule(new KotlinModule())
```

Comment: For generating parameterless constructor I added default values to Kotlin class fields.

Comment: I'm assuming there are other issues with serialisation of Kotlin data classes by Jackson, otherwise they would not have bothered with creating a separate module just for this.

Comment: But how can I say to Json.decodeValue() that it should use 'jackson-module-kotlin'?

Comment: @GlebKosteiko i'm not sure what you mean by "generating parameterless constructor", but be careful not to confuse a constructor with default-able parameters with a default constructor. they're not the same.

Comment: @hsl hm, looks like I just confused these two concepts, as you cautioned.

Comment: @GlebKosteiko follow the link Konrad posted in his answer and read the section titled `Usage`. you can find details there on how to associate the library with your application's `ObjectMapper` instance.

Comment: I added code for configuring Jackson mappers used by Json class

Comment: Thank you all for help:)

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I create kotlin class DTO instance in java for consuming RESTful Api. 
Now I have 2 solutions tested:

1. Use parameterless constructor in data class.

The [reference](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html) kotlin says:

> On the JVM, if all of the parameters of the primary constructor have
>   default values, the compiler will generate an additional parameterless
>   constructor which will use the default values. This makes it easier to
>   use Kotlin with libraries such as Jackson or JPA that create class
>   instances through parameterless constructors.

So I have a DTO in kotlin like this:

```
    data class Dto (
        var id: Int?=null,
        var version: Int?=null, 
        var title: String?=null,
        var firstname: String?=null,
        var lastname: String?=null,
        var birthdate: String?=null

)
```

Then, I create class instance DTO in java:

```
Dto dto = new Dto();
dto.setId(javadto.getId());
...
```

2. Use plugin [jackson-module-kotlin](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-kotlin)

`import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty`

```
    data class Dto (
            @JsonProperty("id") var id: Int?,
            @JsonProperty("version") var version: Int?, 
            @JsonProperty("title") var title: String?,
            @JsonProperty("firstname") var firstname: String?,
            @JsonProperty("lastname") var lastname: String?,
            @JsonProperty("birthdate") var birthdate: String?,

    )
```

Then, I create class instance DTO in java:

```
Dto dto = new Dto(null, null, null, null, null, null);
dto.setId(javadto.getId());
...
```